# Hide main menu using media queries

Tags: html, css

In my website i have menu navigation as follows:

```
   <nav id="main-menu" class="menu-wrapper col-md-12 collapse navbar-collapse mynavbar">
    <ul id="mn_menu" class="menu nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="<?=site_url()?>">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=site_url()?>section/about-us">About Us</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=site_url()?>section/services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=site_url()?>section/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
```

On large screens i want to hide this menu.So when i write the following in my CSS file then it does not hide the menu

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
   #mn_menu {
     display: none;
   }
}
```

However when i use inline css like given below then it hides the menu

```
<ul id="mn_menu" class="menu nav navbar-nav" style="display:none;">
```

Please advise how to hide my menu from the CSS file using media queries.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `min-width` instead of `max-width`. `min-width` means it will apply the CSS rules below as long as the browser width is above or equal to `992px`.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
   #mn_menu {
     display: none;
   }
}
```